# Scope of Random Seed setting

Tags: julia

I want to make a function that will always return the same numbers if I input a parameter asking for a deterministic response and will give a requested number of pseudorandom numbers otherwise. Unfortunately the only way I can figure out how to do it resets the global random seed which is not desirable.

Is there a way I can set the random number seed for one draw of pseudorandom numbers without affecting the global seed or the existing progression along that seed's pseudorandom number sequence?

### Example Case

```
using Random
function get_random(n::Int, deterministic::Bool)
    if deterministic
        Random.seed!(1234)
        return rand(n)
    else
        return rand(n)
    end
end

Random.seed!(4321)
# This and the next get_random(5,false) should give the same response 
# if the Random.seed!(1234) were confined to the function scope.
get_random(5,false)
Random.seed!(4321)
get_random(5,true)
get_random(5,false)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use newly allocated RNG like this:

```
using Random

function get_random(n::Int, deterministic::Bool)
    if deterministic
        m = MersenneTwister(1234)
        return rand(m, n)
    else
        return rand(n)
    end
end
```

In general I usually tend not to use global RNG in simulations at all as it gives me a better control of the process.